# Автоматическая сборка мусора в программах на С++

Tags: c++, c++11, сборщик-мусора

Как ?

Какие фичи для упрощения GC есть в редакции С++11 ?

Основы управления памятью в С++ (переопределение new/delete для классов, для которых мы хотим странного):

- http://www.cantrip.org/wave12.html
- http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/C++-mem-mgnt4.pdf

Сборка мусора:

[A garbage collector for C and C++ - Hans Boehm](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/)

Comment: Чисто не там где убирают, а там где не сорют.

Comment: Сборщик мусора - насколько я понимаю - библиотека. это в с# сборщик интегрирован, а у с++ штатного нету. И с++11 штатного так же нету. Вот какие функции есть у вашей мусорной библиотеки - такими и располагаете.

Comment: @nick_n_a, а как же shared_ptr и компания?

Comment: Их очень мало и они умещаются в одну [страницу](http://eel.is/c++draft/util.dynamic.safety). Пока, GC для C++ в стандарте нет.

Comment: @Dmitry Ponyatov  Нет никаких средств в C++ для упрощения создания GC. Проблема состоит в том, что нужно менять сам язык, так как необходимо будет менять идеологию работы с ресурсами в клиентском коде. Поэтому если вам так нужен GC, то имейте дело с C++/CLI.

Comment: @Dmitry Ponyatov: Возможно, есть смысл посмотреть в сторону управляемых языков. C# или Java вполне хороши на текущий день. А какая у вас задача? (ЗЫ: Если это что-то насчёт синтаксического разбора, может быть вам пригодится [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/index.html).)

Comment: @DmitryPonyatov Какой-то у вас прям желтый заголовок получисля

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Это девиз ленивых дворников? :-P

Comment: Я хочу напомнить, что есть несколько моделей памяти: пул, куча, GC. Для всех трех видов памяти есть функция вроде Enumerate. Я думаю что нужно озвучить возможности современных средств управления GC, кучи, и пулов. А возможсти такие - что вопрос должен уйти. Можно снимать статистику по разным параметрам - и получить "диагноз". Вопрос больше - какой результат вы хотите.

Answer (score 9):

В C++ нет и не может быть средств сборки мусора. Вместо этого можно использовать умные указатели. Наиболее универсальный из них - `shared_ptr`. В конструктор умного указателя нужно передать указатель на уже выделенную память, и больше нигде этот указатель использовать нельзя. При копировании объекта `shared_ptr`, при передаче его как параметр функции увеличивается внутренний счётчик объектов, имеющих в себе один и тот же указатель. Как только последний объект `shared_ptr` уничтожается (выходит из области видимости), автоматически освобождается память, на которую ссылается внутренний указатель `shared_ptr`. Вот пример использования.

```
void foo()
{
    //Создаём умный указатель, передав ему обычный указатель на массив из 10 целых чисел
    std::shared_ptr<int> x(new int(10));
    //Вызываем функцию, которая использует этот указатель. На стеке создаётся копия объекта x, которая указывает на ту же память
    bar(x);
    //Заканчивается область видимости, удаляется x, освобождается память по данному указателю
}
void bar(std::shared_ptr<int> y)
{
    //Функция работает со своей копией объекта
    y[5] = 10;
    //Область видимости закочилась, объект y удаляется, но так как есть ещё один такой же умный указатель, память не освобождается
}
```

Comment: Стоит добавить, что `shared_ptr` имеет недостаток: кольцевые ссылки требуют ручного разрыва цикла (что вынуждает всё равно заботиться о точном моменте уничтожения структуры данных).

Comment: @VladD, `weak_ptr`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb weak_ptr умеет находить и разрывать кольцевые ссылки?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb: Ну, во-первых, этого нет в ответе, а во-вторых, добавляется задача правильной расстановки типов указателей, чтобы нужная структура данных случайно не оказалось без сильных ссылок. Это вполне может оказаться нетривиально для нетривиальных отношений между объектами (то есть, там где нету самоочевидного дерева).

Comment: @maestro: Хм, не уверен, а _как_ будет удалена память? Через `delete` или через `delete[]`?

Comment: @VladD, раньше не задумывался, так как использовал умные указатели только для классов. Но в любом случае в конструкторе `shared_ptr` можно указать `deleter`.

Comment: @VladD, нет, мой пример неправильный. У `shared_ptr` нет оператора `[]`. Обратиться к элементу массива можно через разыменовывание, но всё равно придётся указывать `deleter`.

Comment: @Cerbo, находить - нет, разрывать - да